# Making a map import option

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a parkour game with a default map in unity but i'm making it simple to get the feel of unity because i'm new, anyway, I don't want to make a bunch of levels and as a gamer, I absolutely love to import my own levels, I was thinking I would be able to make the game read from a folder called 'maps' when it loads and gives a selection of options of the maps in that folder, how would I be able to accomplish this???

Comment: This is a very broad question, probably not suitable for Stack Overflow. It is absolutely possible to build tools that can read in levels dynamically, but it's not easy nor is it quick to explain. Aside from learning game development, you may want to learn about serialization (such as reading and writing data to files).

Comment: Fair enough, I might as well just make a suggestion board or something XD

Answer (score 0):

This will require 2 steps: encoding the map data and loading it at a later date

You would need to create the map in Unity and then use some standard of data encoding to save the map data as a file for you to load later. The most common way I've seen this done is by using [JSON Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html). The Unity article I linked does a very good job explaning how to encode your data using this format.

After you have encoded and saved your file, you will need some way to load the appropriate map data. So, you will need to load the JSON file you save and then handle the data from that file to build your map.

A tip: Find the "things" that make a map unique. For example if everything is the same in your levels except the locations of the walls or something, just save the locations of your walls and plop them in place when you load the map later.

Comment: Thanks ill give this a try!